# Is there a bee hive that works with a tap?

Tags: bee-attractive

I'm currently building a king stropharia bed, so I'm wondering if I could collect honey on a tap without really disturbing the bees as a function stacked on top of the mushroom function.

My neighbor is a beekeeper, but won't give me any free honey.

Comment: Nope - see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_extraction. You have to remove the comb and break the caps on each cell. Has it not occurred to you to offer to pay your neighbour for his honey? After all, its a lot of work keeping bees and collecting the honey

Comment: i thought i saw something on shark tank, i guess not

Comment: @Bamboo what about flow hives?

Comment: Never heard of 'em, but here's a link https://www.honeyflow.com. Even so, all the usual strict rules about beekeeping still apply, and I'm not sure you will want to do all that http://www.beesbros.com/how-to-keep-bees.html

Comment: I'm a beekeeper, and it is expensive, time consuming, and a lot of work to keep bees healthy.  Gone are the days to just slap a bee colony in a box and have them produce for you year after year.  I'm not sure what honey and your mushroom have to do with each other, but in order to produce 1 pound of honey, 2 million flowers must be visited and the hive of bees must fly 55,000 miles to produce a pound of honey.  Buy some of the cheap grocery store garbage and use that for you mushroom @$6/#.  Local honey is easily worth twice that. To start beekeeping is $500 buy in, give your neighbor a break.

Comment: bee health: https://fungi.com/blogs/articles/bee-friendly-research-update-3
I can bring my honey to the neighbor (across the creek) to process for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are at least two companies who offer a product like this, but they do cost a bit of money and I'm not sure if it really reduces the total effort of keeping bees.

- [tapcomb](https://tapcomb.com/)
- [Honey Flow](https://www.honeyflow.com/)

If you do use one or experiment with this, I hope you'll post a comment in the future with the results of your experiment.

Comment: Tapcomb was a rip of of the FlowHive and they have gone under thankfully as of Nov 2018.